# Can i force empty date object to be reassigned?

Tags: javascript, date, sorting

I am doing a to-do list, everything else works fine, but there's one issue that keeps bothering me.
Since I don't want to set the date and the time as required input, so sometimes the date and time will be left blanket. But when I sorted the date ascending, the empty date's row will just pop up to the top. I hope it always is put to the bottom, no matter how I sort it. I tried to reassign the date to '2100-11-30T00:00:00'before compare function, but it's not working, and the console shows "Invalid Date". So I just wondering if there's any way to fix it? or Any solution to solve this problem?

```
const dateDown = document.querySelector(".dateDown")
dateDown.addEventListener("click", () => {

    let arrayList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("theList"));
    arrayList.sort(function (a, b) {
        let aDate = new Date(a.date) + a.time;
        let bDate = new Date(b.date) + b.time;

        if (aDate === null) {
            aDate = new Date('2100-11-30T00:00:00');
        }
        console.log(aDate, bDate);
        if (aDate < bDate) {
            return 1;
        } else if (aDate > bDate) {
            return -1;
        } else if (aDate == bDate) {
            return 0;
        }
    })
```

Comment: Something like `if (!a.date && !a.time) return -1;` and `if (!b.date && !b.time) return 1;` at the start of the function should work (if not, swap 1 and -1)

Comment: Can you please post an example value of `arrayList`? It's not clear where you are getting "*Invalid date*".

Comment: `if (aDate === null)` will never hold, `aDate` is always a number. You're looking for `if (a.date == null)`. Also you'll need to do the same for `b.date`, and you should use `Infinity` not some arbitrary "large date".

Comment: Thank you Chris for replaying, but it's still not working...

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your response. I tried the method you said, still got invalid date
one of the array's object is like this'
 check: "false"
date: "2020-11-30"
priority: "20"
task: "20"
time: "05:05" '

Comment: @Bergi The empty date one is like this: ' check: "false"
date: ""
priority: ""
task: "empty"
time: "" '

Comment: Wait, I think the first attempt with @Bergi 's method, there's something wrong on my side. Now I tried again and it works!! Thank you you guys!!

Comment: @Joe Ah, `date: ""` is not the same as `date: null`, which is what the condition is checking. You'll need to use `if (a.date == "")` or `if (!a.date)` then. (And same for `b`).

Comment: You need to post an example of the value assigned to *arrayList*. That you haven't done that is why you are getting so many questions with no suitable answers. Also, don't put additional information in comments, put it in the question. Code like `new Date(a.date) + a.time` is not sensible and points to many possible errors.

Comment: Also, `aDate === null` will never be true, nor will `aDate == null`.